# Vue.js update not triggered when property changed inside a WebRTC callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webrtc

I'm trying to create a small Vue.js component that takes permissions for the camera and microphone from the user and displays that stream on a canvas. Simple enough, right?

But in reality, I couldn't get Vue.js to update the src property of my `video` tag so I added a simple `status` message to test if the changes are being picked up by Vue. They aren't. How do I ensure that the Vue picks up the property changes inside the `getUserMedia` callback?

Please see the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/49r0c4cf/

And here's the code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="getPermissions()" >Get permissions</button>
    <video v-bind:src="videoStreamSrc" autoplay></video>
    <h1>{{status}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      videoStreamSrc: null,
      status: 'default',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPermissions() {
      this.status = 'FETHCING';
      const vm = this;
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: true,
      }, () => {
        // vm.videoStreamSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(localMediaStream);
        vm.$set('status', 'DONE');
      }, (err) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.error(err);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Return_value), `getUserMedia` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you should be using it like...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  autio: true
}).then(stream => {
  this.status = 'DONE'
}, err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/49r0c4cf/1/

Comment: Damn! I feel stupid for not opening the actual documentation. I was blindly following this [HTML5Rocks link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) to get started